# NSMutableDictionary returning null value ? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

After @implementation and before viewDidLoad I declare my NSMutableDictionary as follows :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
```

Then in my viewDidLoad method I try this :

```
[dictionary setObject:@"test" forKey:@"haha"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"haha"]);
```

The NSLog returns a null value :

> (null)

I would like to know why that happens, it should return "test", doesnt it ?

Comment: have you inited your `dictionary` anywhere? like e.g. `dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];`...?

Comment: This will work. NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:@"test" forKey:@"haha"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"haha"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to instantiate your dictionary first:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
```

Then it will be ready to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this works fine. I used to work with swift and had to go back to some old Obj-C so I forgot those habits.